# In how many ways can the letters of english alphabets is arranged given the following conditions?

Tags: permutations, combinations

> In how many ways can the letters of english alphabets is arranged so that there are 7 letters between the letters A & B and no letter is repeated?

**MyApproach**

we select 7 letters from 26-2(exclude a,b)

so we select 24p7 ways

and we arraged in 2 ways(start with either a or b)

reamining 18 in 18! ways

finally 24p7*2*18!

> Am I right in my approach.Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: I think that's right, with the AxxxxxxxB or BxxxxxxxA counting as one of the 18.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes,It must be 18.I think I did a typo.

Comment: I was wrong. Your calculation is fine.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Out of 24 we select 7 and remaining 17 are left?

Comment: Yes, but there is also the "abstract" letter $axxxxxxxb$, which can be permuted together with the $17$ leftover "real" letters.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I solved the above problem as keeping a,b fixed we arrange remaining letters in (a 1.2.3.4.5.6.7 b) in $24$P$7$!. This can also be done as (b 1.2.3.4.5.6.7 a).Thus,I multiplied by $2$ as either way the arrangement can be made.Other($24$-7=) $17$ letters can be arranged in 17! ways.

Comment: A correct answer is $({}_{24}P_7)(2)(18!)$.

Answer (score 3):

*Another approach*

$A$ can be fixed at $1$ through $18$, which automatically positions $B$ in the order $A.......B$,  and by interchanging $A$ and $B$, we get $2\cdot18$ positions for the $A-B$ duo.

The remaining $24$ letters can be permuted in positions available for them in $24!$ ways,

hence $2\cdot18\cdot24!$ ways